# C Efficient way to find prime number in interval k^3 to (k + 1)^3

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

In the lecture, we were told that there is at least one prime number between k³ and (k + 1)³ for all k > 1. I would now like to know how to find such a prime number *efficiently* in C. I know the Sieve of Eratosthenes yet I have no clue how to implement it without polluting memory. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you believe you would be polluting memory with your implementation? Would you really need to create anything dynamically?

Comment: It might help if you provided the proof.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Unfortunately, the professor didn't show the proof as it wasn't a lecture about math but about algorithms and thus computer science oriented.

Comment: @Kozmik I'll need to allocate memory for all the numbers between k³ and (k + 1)³, I think. If not, it would be great, that's the purpose of the question

Comment: @OliverBorchert makes sense. I was asking more about the fact of whether you just needed a count of all prime numbers between that upper and lower bounds or the actual prime numbers between them - it seemed you just needed at least one prime (not all of them).

Comment: @Kozmik yes that's right, just one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *need to* pollute your memory to increase the speed of finding the prime number. There is a simple approach that is fast and simple to implement.

```
primes = list of prime number below sqrt( (k+1)^3 )
for i = k^3 + 1 to (k+1)^3 :
     is_prime = true
     for p in primes:
           if (i % p == 0) :
              is_prime = false
              break
     if (is_prime):
          print(i)
```

For generating the list of prime number below sqrt ( (k+1)^3 ), you can use Sieve of Eratosthenes. With this approach, you will only need to use at most  (k+1)<sup>1.5</sup> of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends very much on the size of *k*. If *k* is small, less than 10**3 or thereabouts, the Sieve of Eratosthenes will work well. But if *k* is larger, a better approach is to use a Miller-Rabin pseudoprimality test:

```
function isPrime(n, k=5)
    if n < 2 then return False
    for p in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
        if n % p == 0 then return n == p
    s, d = 0, n-1
    while d % 2 == 0
        s, d = s+1, d/2
    for i from 0 to k
        x = powerMod(randint(2, n-1), d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n-1 then next i
        for r from 1 to s
            x = (x * x) % n
            if x == 1 then return False
            if x == n-1 then next i
        return False
    return True
```

With that, you can test each odd number starting at *k* cubed. It shouldn't take long to find a prime.